# How to include a relatively-placed image from a .cls?

Tags: graphics, document-classes

This is my `foo.cls`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{foo}[test]
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\printIt{\includegraphics{images/pic.pdf}}
```

The file `images/pic.pdf` stays next to the `foo.cls`.

Then, this is my `bar.tex`, which is in some other directory:

```
\documentclass{/code/foo/foo}
\begin{document}
\printIt
\end{document}
```

I'm getting:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `images/pic.pdf' not found.
```

What is the right way to reference the picture from `.cls`?

Comment: it is bad practice to put paths in `\documentclass` the argument is a name of the class not a file name, if you just use `\documentclass{foo}` and `\includegraphics{pic.pdf}` then they can both be found if you put the files in the tex input path. If you do use any relative input path in tex it is relative to the working dorectory of the tex process, not relative to any file.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I totally understand that it's a bad practice, but in my situation, I have to do it this way

Comment: why can't you use `TEXINPUTS=/code//:  pdflatex file` and `\documentclass{foo}`  ?but in either case, the argument to `\includegraphics` is relative to the working directory of pdftex, not to the file